# Prove when n=2, the sample variance follows the chi square distribution with 1 degrees of freedom

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, convolution, chi-squared

I am quite new so correct me if I am doing anything wrong, and sorry for my inability to understand how LATEX works.

So my question is regarding the special case when $n=2$, the sample variance formula collapses down to the sum of $(X_1 - \bar{x})^2 + (X_2 - \bar{x})^2$ where $X_i$ follows the standard normal distribution, while $\bar{x}$ follows the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1/2$.

When attempting this question, I thought about trying to first use the convolution formula to find the distribution of $Z=X-Y$, then do a transformation of $Q=Z^2$, and then lastly use convolution again for the sum of the resulting distribution.

However, when attempting the first step I arrived at an integral that is very apparently incorrect. What I arrived at was the integral from negative infinity to positive infinity of $f_x(x)*f_y(Z+X)dx$.

I arrived at this through the consideration of the plane I need to integrate, under $Z=X-Y$, one consider the plane $X-Y$, where $Y=X-Z$ and when considering the $P(X-Y<Z)$, one should integrate from negative infinity to infinity for $y$ and negative infinity to $Z+Y$, and through finding the double integral, and differentiatinf the inner integral, it resulted in the above formula. Which when tried to plug in the distribution, I could not result in a meaningful answer, I would like someone to point out to me where did I go wrong, as I agree that my method of obtaining $Z=X-Y$ seems dodgy.

Thanks a lot for reading, and sorry about the lack of mathematical notations, as I am really not familiar with how one uses it.

Comment: **"...when tried to plug in the distribution, I could not result in a meaningful answer..."** The setup you described $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x) f_Y(z+x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ is correct and there's nothing dodgy about it. You should be able to obtain another Gaussian, as it is a standard integration and there's nothing tricky. Of course there are other ways to obtain the final result as a Chi-sq, but this approach is fine.

Comment: Sorry, my stat knowledge is pretty basic, can you elaborate on what is a gaussian? Thanks

Comment: Gaussian is just another name for Normal distribution. I personally use it because saying something like "$X$ is Normal" or "$Y$ is not Normal" might carry some unwanted connotation.

Comment: Notice that when $n=2,$ you have $(X_1 - \bar X)^2$ = $(X_2 - \bar X)^2 = \left(\frac{X_1-X_2}{2}\right)^2$ Then use that the third form is the square of a normal random variable.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin For some reason my integral for the question is as so [Integral](https://imgur.com/a/BRKmMIw), which result in [this](https://imgur.com/a/2RO25mK), and through the transformation of the distribution y=X^2 I got the result of (e^(-y/3))/root(3y*pi), and use convolution of the sum of 2 variables Z=Y_1+Y_2, where Y_1 and Y_2 has the same distribution, i got an exponential distribution with mean 3, which is not the thing I am trying to prove, and I would like to know where it went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The first density (left) in your figure below (as linked in your comment) should correspond to the $\color{magenta}{\text{magenta}}$ term $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)\, \color{magenta}{f_Y(z+x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \qquad \text{where} \quad f_Y(t) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{ t^2 }2} \tag{1} \label{Eq01}$$

[image]

When you plugin $t = z+x$ in Eq.\eqref{Eq01}, the leading factor $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ is not affected, neither is the $2$ in the denominator in the exponent.

Could you explain the "some reason" you said in the comment "For some reason my integral for the question is as so..."? ***Why is your left term involving $x+z$ scaled by $\sqrt{2}$ overall and by 2 in the exponent?***

Note that Eq.\eqref{Eq01} is exactly what you described as (let me quote verbatim)

> "... What I arrived at was the integral from negative infinity to positive infinity of $f_x(x)*f_y(Z+X)dx$."

where your star $*$ is absolutely just a  multiplication (and you didn't object to my use of central dot $\cdot$ in my comment). Your entire sentence (starting from "the integral") describes correctly the convolution $f_X \otimes f_Y$. There should be no way for you to have mistakenly viewed the $*$ as meaning yet another convolution $f_X \otimes f_{X+Z}$ ... I guess.

Comment: I did so assuming we have Z=X-Y, where X is standard normal and Y normal with mean 0 and variance 1/2, as it is X bar. So since [This graph if z is 5](https://imgur.com/a/CDISPeT) this is the region where i integrate, therefore the integral is from  negative infinity to infinity in relation to Y. And negative infinity up to Z+Y for X. This results in an integral with Y in the outer integral and x as inner.

Therefore when considering X-Xbar, I integrated the X bar function first and multiplied with the X distribution with (Z+X)

Comment: The main thing aboutIt took you THIS long to finally state that you take $Y \equiv \bar{X}$. When you start with $X_1 - \bar{X}$, the next logical step is to see it as $X_1 - (X_1 + X_2)/2 = (X_1 - X_2)/2$. This is crucial because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, only then can you do convolution. To find the density of this thing, first you find the density of $X_1 - X_2$, because scaling by 2 afterwarrds is easy. This is what I meant by $Z = X - Y$ all the time as $Y = X_2$ (Okay so now I know why you up-ed BruceET's comment because you never looked at it this way)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I always thought I should have just used the X bar distribution rather than expand it into just difference of standard normal. Thanks a lot, after some fiddling i obtained that S^2=[(X_1-X_2)^2]/2, and i was stuck at the integral of exp(-0.5(x^2+(Z+x)^2))and realised i should make it a(x-c)^2 + d, and got the integration.

Then after getting the pdf of X_1-X_2, I use the transformation Y=0.5Z^2, and resulting in the chi squared distribution 1 degrees of freedom.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Doing convolution on $X$ and $\bar{X}$ is incorrect from the get-go. Convolution applies only when two random variables are independent. Seriously you kept talking about convolution and I thought you knew what you were doing.

Comment: Sorry, this is my second week after encountering what convolution and sum of random variables, so I am really bad at it atm. Need to do more practices.

Comment: I apologize if my last couple of comments came across as harsh. I'm sorry I got carried away. Actually you're not the one who needs to say sorry. I myself have asked several very basic questions here and elsewhere in the StackExchange network, and by and large people treated me kindly. That's why I stayed. There are indeed shortcomings with the current system (that magnify people's aggressiveness). I hope you can make good use of this platform whenever you need to.